# JavaFX Creating an Image and ImageView

Tags: image, javafx, imageview

Stuck in the basics. I have some syntax issues setting up the Image Path.
When i try to create an Image and give it the image path, it always throws some some exception about the path. I have commented out some of the path combination I have already tryed. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

package jopofx;

```
public JoPoCTRL(JoPoFX gui){
    this.gui = gui;  
}

public void updateImages(){
    Image img = null;
    try{
        //img = new Image("C:\\Users\\ ... //FullPath ... \\JoPoFX\\src\\jopofx\\myimage.png");
        img = new Image("\\JoPoFX\\src\\jopofx\\myimage.png");
        //img = new Image("\\src\\jopofx\\myimage.png");
        //img = new Image("\\myimage.png");

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("error while creating image");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try{
        gui.setImgV(img);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("error while setting up the image");
    }        
}
```

This is what prints out:
error while creating image
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:990)
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.(Image.java:538)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working example from a blog short after I posted my question.
Hopefully this example will be helpful to someone:

```
InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/"+imageName+".jpg");
//"images/" is the a local directory where all my images are located
Image newImage = new Image(stream); 
imgV.setImage(newImage);
```

Answer (score 2):

On `Windows` platform, for an image placed inside `src/jopofx` :

```
img = new Image("\\jopofx\\myimage.png");
```

or

```
img = new Image("/jopofx/myimage.png");
```

Then you can create an ImageView using:

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(img);
```

Further, you can also directly initialize an `ImageView` without initializing an `Image` by:

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView("/jopofx/myimage.png");
```

Also, make sure you are using the import `javafx.scene.image.Image;`

Comment: Thank you for your answer ItachiUchiha.
For some reason non of those syntaxes either worked. 
I have a myimage.png file in both /JoPoFX/src and JoPoFX/src/jopofx/ folders.
(The last one is the folder where the code is run from)
If you have any other suggestions, I would be happy to hear them?
Thank you

Comment: I forgot to mention. I do have imported javafx.scene.image.Image;

Comment: Hi. I think I found a solution. Instead of typing the path, I had to to write "file:\\C:users\\.....\\myimage.png.
My program does not crush anymore but I haven't yet been able to make the image visible. So there is no way to be sure yet that this works.

Comment: Adding the absolute path for an image located inside you project is not a good idea. Moreover, if you have packaged your application as `jar` and trying to load the image using `file:`, it will fail. I advise you to post an image of your project structure so that I can help you further.

Comment: Looks like I cannot upload any images, because I dont have enough "reputation". Here is a link where I uploaded the image of my project structure. --> http://users.metropolia.fi/~joonaen/openDir/projectStructure.png
I actually never got the ImageView showing the image, when typing the "file:\C:\ ... \ myimage.png" into the Image/ImageView constructor , but I did managed to get the ImageView showing by typing in the website address where I uploaded the photo to. But it is not a final solution that i want to be using...